# Rewriting custom tag attributes using IIS Url Rewrite 2.0 and ARR

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, custom-tags, arr

I've developed a custom grid control that uses `data-*` attributes to configure how the grid is supposed to work (in a similar vein to how Bootstrap data API components work. For a particular deployment, I'm having to proxy my web application into another web application using IIS and Application Request Routing (ARR) + URL Rewrite. The proxying part is all done, I'm currently trying to configure the outbound rules for rewriting urls to match. For instance, I currently have rules set up such as:

- Rewrite HTTP redirects by updating the `Location:` header.
- Rewrite Html content for URIs in standard tags (e.g., A, Area, base, etc.)
- Rewrite Css content for URI's that are relative (e.g. /cassette.axd -> /blog/cassette.axd).

The last issue I am having, is getting the URL rewrite module to accept my urls in data attributes, e.g., if my grid is such like:

```
<table data-grid data-query="/api/users/">
```

Should be rewritten as

```
<table data-grid data-query="/blog/api/users/">
```

I stress that all other tags, such as `<a href` and `<img src` work as expected and even a custom `<property value` tag is correctly rewritten. Just seems to by hypenated attributes.

I've tried adding a `<customTags>` section, with my custom tags in:

```
<customTags>
    <tags name="Bootgrid">
        <tag name="table" attribute="data-query" />
        <tag name="table" attribute="data-update" />
        <!-- This next tag WORKS -->
        <tag name="property" attribute="value" />
    </tags>
</customTags>
```

However, the above is not matching any attributes that have a hyphen. Not sure if this is actually solvable or not because I can't see anything in IIS configuration to set these.

Also annoyingly once you've created a set of Custom Tags in IIS, you can't seem to edit them again. :-/

Comment: For what it's worth after testing I have the exact same behavior here. Only info I found is this: http://forums.iis.net/t/1162172.aspx/1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and it appears (although not confirmed by Microsoft) that IIS cannot handle a custom tag that contains a -

A work around that worked for me was to use another outbound Rule. In this example I am attempting to replace the data-zoom-image attribute within an img tag (You will need to replace the **&lt;img** with **&lt;table** and **data-zoom-image** with **data-query** in both the "match" and "action"

```
<rule name="RewriteRelativePathsCustomTags1" preCondition="IsHtml" enabled="true">
    <match filterByTags="None" pattern="&lt;img ([^>]*)data-zoom-image=&quot;(.*?)&quot;([^>]*)>" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="&lt;img {R:1}data-zoom-image=&quotYOUR VALUE TO REWRITE i.e /blog{R:2}&quot;{R:3}>" />
</rule>
<preConditions>
    <preCondition name="IsHtml">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
    </preCondition>
</preConditions>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

ARR on IIS seems to have issues with tags that include attributes with a dash (-) in them.

Updating to v3.0.1952 seems to have solved the issue for me, but I'm still investigating.

Comment: I meant URL Rewrite 7.2.1952, not ARR.

Answer (score 0):

Rather belated, but this was [fixed back in 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47337) in the Release To Web version (2.0.1952):

> **IMPORTANT - Changes in this release**
>
> - Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 Support - It is now possible to install URL Rewrite Module 2.0 on Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016 with this release
> - Custom attributes containing dashes are now supported. This is required as HTML 5 has the following rules for determining HTML attribute names: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes
> - Incorporates Hotfix for URL Rewrite 2.0 (June 2014) as in KB2974666